# How to hide one picklist based on other picklist values

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm having two pick list based on 1st picklist values 2nd picklist must be displayed. I tried in two ways but its not working.

**Way 1: using rerendered in VF page**

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Item" for="item"/>
    <apex:selectList id="item" value="{!selectedItem}"  size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Colum Two" for="Two"/>
    <apex:selectList id="Two" value="{!selectedItem1 }"  rendered="{!selectedItem == 'Math JrBg || Math SrBg|| Math 0a || English SrBg || Abacus Jr Level 2  || Abacus Sr Level 1 || Abacus Jr Level 1 || Abacus Sr Level 2' }" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items1}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

---

```
public List<SelectOption>  getItems()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('--Select an Item--','--Select an Item--'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Pens - Qty 50' , 'Pens - Qty 50'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Pencils - Qty 50','Pencils - Qty 50'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Blue Draw String Bags - Qty 10','Blue Draw String Bags - Qty 10'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('BestBrains Bags-Zip Type - Qty 50','BestBrains Bags-Zip Type - Qty 50'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('$1 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs','$1 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('$10 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs','$10 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('Progress Books - Qty 20','Progress Books - Qty 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Tools - Qty 20','Abacus Tools - Qty 20'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('Master Abacus - Qty 1 ','Master Abacus - Qty 1 '));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Parent Curriculum Charts - Qty 20','Parent Curriculum Charts - Qty 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Owner Curriculum Chart - Qty 1','Owner Curriculum Chart - Qty 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Math Certificates - Qty 20','Math Certificates - Qty 20'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('English Certificates - Qty 20','English Certificates - Qty 20'));   
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Certificates - Qty 20','Abacus Certificates - Qty 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('General Knowledge Certificates - Qty - 20','General Knowledge Certificates - Qty - 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus JR Level 1 Workbook - Qty 10' , 'Abacus JR Level 1 Workbook - Qty 10'));


        options.add(new SelectOption('Math JrBg' , 'Math JrBg'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Math SrBg','Math SrBg'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Math 0a','Math 0a'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('English SrBg','English SrBg'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Jr Level 1','Abacus Jr Level 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Jr Level 2','Abacus Jr Level 2'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Sr Level 1','Abacus Sr Level 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Sr Level 2','Abacus Sr Level 2'));


        return options ;
    }



     public List<SelectOption>  getItems1()
    {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('A - Qty 5','A - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('B - Qty 5','B - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('C - Qty 5','C - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('D - Qty 5','D - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('E - Qty 5','E - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('F - Qty 5','F - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('G - Qty 5','G - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('H - Qty 5','H - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('I - Qty 5','I - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('J - Qty 5','J - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('K - Qty 5','K - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('L - Qty 5','L - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('M - Qty 5','M - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('N - Qty 5','N - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('O - Qty 5','O - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('P - Qty 5','P - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Q - Qty 5','Q - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('R - Qty 5','R - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('S - Qty 5','S - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('T - Qty 5','T - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('U - Qty 5','U - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('V - Qty 5','V - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('W - Qty 5','W - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('X - Qty 5','X - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Y - Qty 5','Y - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Z - Qty 5','Z - Qty 5'));


        return options ;
    }
```

**Way 2 ::  Using IF condition in controller**

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Item" for="item"/>
    <apex:selectList id="item" value="{!selectedItem }"  size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Colum Two" for="Two"/>
    <apex:selectList id="Two" value="{!selectedItem1 }" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items1}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

---

```
public List<SelectOption>  getItems()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('--Select an Item--','--Select an Item--'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Pens - Qty 50' , 'Pens - Qty 50'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Pencils - Qty 50','Pencils - Qty 50'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Blue Draw String Bags - Qty 10','Blue Draw String Bags - Qty 10'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('BestBrains Bags-Zip Type - Qty 50','BestBrains Bags-Zip Type - Qty 50'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('$1 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs','$1 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('$10 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs','$10 Bucks - Qty 500 pcs'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('Progress Books - Qty 20','Progress Books - Qty 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Tools - Qty 20','Abacus Tools - Qty 20'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('Master Abacus - Qty 1 ','Master Abacus - Qty 1 '));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Parent Curriculum Charts - Qty 20','Parent Curriculum Charts - Qty 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Owner Curriculum Chart - Qty 1','Owner Curriculum Chart - Qty 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Math Certificates - Qty 20','Math Certificates - Qty 20'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('English Certificates - Qty 20','English Certificates - Qty 20'));   
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Certificates - Qty 20','Abacus Certificates - Qty 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('General Knowledge Certificates - Qty - 20','General Knowledge Certificates - Qty - 20'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus JR Level 1 Workbook - Qty 10' , 'Abacus JR Level 1 Workbook - Qty 10'));


        options.add(new SelectOption('Math JrBg' , 'Math JrBg'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Math SrBg','Math SrBg'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Math 0a','Math 0a'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('English SrBg','English SrBg'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Jr Level 1','Abacus Jr Level 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Jr Level 2','Abacus Jr Level 2'));  
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Sr Level 1','Abacus Sr Level 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Abacus Sr Level 2','Abacus Sr Level 2'));


        return options ;
    }

public List<SelectOption>  getItems1() 
    {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(selectedItem == 'Abacus Sr Level 2')
        options.add(new SelectOption('A - Qty 5','A - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('B - Qty 5','B - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('C - Qty 5','C - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('D - Qty 5','D - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('E - Qty 5','E - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('F - Qty 5','F - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('G - Qty 5','G - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('H - Qty 5','H - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('I - Qty 5','I - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('J - Qty 5','J - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('K - Qty 5','K - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('L - Qty 5','L - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('M - Qty 5','M - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('N - Qty 5','N - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('O - Qty 5','O - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('P - Qty 5','P - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Q - Qty 5','Q - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('R - Qty 5','R - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('S - Qty 5','S - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('T - Qty 5','T - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('U - Qty 5','U - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('V - Qty 5','V - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('W - Qty 5','W - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('X - Qty 5','X - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Y - Qty 5','Y - Qty 5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Z - Qty 5','Z - Qty 5'));


        return options ;
    }
```

Comment: Hi kiran, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. Your question is not very clear. Please **[edit]** your post to be more explicit about what you mean by *it's not working*.

Comment: Hi Larson, I'm having two pick lists, in the 1st pick list for some values only 2nd picklist values must be enabled.

Comment: I tried rerendered func, IF condition both are not working

Answer (score 1):

You never **`rerender`** anything. You should add an `<apex:actionSupport>` directly under your `<apex:selectList>` tag (not your `<apex:selectOptions>` tag). Something like the below works just fine:

**Markup**

```
<apex:page controller="RerenderDemo">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="section">

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Option 1" />
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selection1}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options1}" />
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="section" />
                        <!-- CRITICAL TAG ABOVE -->
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!shouldDisplay}">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Option 2" />
                    <apex:selectList value="{!selection2}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options2}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class Throwaway
{
    public List<SelectOption> options1 { get; private set; }
    public List<SelectOption> options2 { get; private set; }

    public String selection1 { get; set; }
    public String selection2 { get; set; }

    public Boolean shouldDisplay { get { system.debug(selection1); return whitelist.contains(selection1); } }

    final Set<String> whitelist = new Set<String> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    public Throwaway()
    {
        options1 = new List<SelectOption>
        {
            new SelectOption('a', 'a'),
            new SelectOption('b', 'b'),
            new SelectOption('c', 'c'),
            new SelectOption('d', 'd'),
            new SelectOption('e', 'e'),
            new SelectOption('f', 'f')
        };
        options2 = new List<SelectOption>
        {
            new SelectOption('x', 'x'),
            new SelectOption('y', 'y'),
            new SelectOption('z', 'z')
        };
        selection1 = 'a';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this revenge now @AdrianLarson?! Beat me to this one in 7 seconds! :D

Comment: Hahaha. Didn't realize you were working on it. :) Does it actually work if you `rerender` the element itself though? The renderer only actually rerenders child elements of whatever you specify. Hmm.

Comment: Looks that way. I didn't copy his code but I don't know if you can see deleted answers, but I just made the worlds most basic select option changer and basically said he was missing an `<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="theIdOfTheRecord" />` in the first list.

Comment: Right, I am referencing your deleted answer. I see that you rerendered the second `selectList`, but I would expect that not to work. I would think you'd have to rerender the `form` instead.

Comment: Give it a try! I didn't know that it only reRendered children, but I suppose from a pure HTML point of view, `<option>` is a child of `<select>` so it would make sense as to why that way works.